# how to add functionality using javascript in angular componet

Tags: arrays, angular

i am making shopping cart project and want to add functionality to add products in cart. is it possible to use scripts in angular the way i provided in code or any other solution

```
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-primary m-2" id="add" routerLink="/addProducts">Add Products</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="btn btn-danger m-2" routerLink="/deleteProducts">Delete</a>
</div>
<script>
  const button = document.getElementById("add");
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("hello");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There's really no need for any script tag as the accompanied `x.ts` file provides the perfect outlet for that. I also suggest you use an actual `button` tag for your `addProducts` operation and call it via a click event. In general, it seems like you're quite new to Angular so I suggest going through the official tutorial first, ie. https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is, it will be hard to manage the state, As for the cart you need to store the cart items and you might want the same items in the next component/page. It increases more complexity it is better to have the scripting code in ts file and keep the flow angular way.

Comment: i should write all functionality in component.ts